# Regular Expression Pattern match for Date

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, date

I am trying to extract the date from the following object (that has been stringified.)

I am new to regular expressions, and not sure how to go about it.

```
I tried /^(\d{4})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})$/gmi  -> but it didnot work.


{"﻿Date":"2016-05-16","Package Name":"com.myapp.mobile","Current Device Installs":"15912","Daily Device Installs":"41","Daily Device Uninstalls":"9","Daily Device Upgrades":"3","Current User Installs":"12406","Total User Installs":"23617","Daily User Installs":"27","Daily User Uninstalls":"8"}
```

Comment: Remove `^` and `$` since those match the start and the end of a line

Comment: Why can't you just parse the JSON string properly? That would be a much better solution. What other examples do you want to match? What do you want it to not match? Could the date be in a different format?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a Regex here.

Do `JSON.parse(str).Date`, unless there is a really good reason not to (you haven't stated one in your question)

If you want to turn the string "2016-05-16" into 3 variables for Year, Month and day (without using a date library), I'd just use `.split()`:

```
dateArray = "2016-05-16".split("-")
var year = dateArray[0], month = dateArray[1], day = dateArray[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex matches fine, just don't use the `/gmi` flags

```
"2016-05-16".match(/^(\d{4})\-(\d{1,2})\-(\d{1,2})$/)
```

You can make it a bit simpler yet..

```
"2016-05-16".match(/(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})/)
```

But, you really should be using a library for this, like [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), or at least [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) which will work fine because this ISO-8601.

```
const date = new Date("2016-05-16");
date.getYear();
```

Comment: Even parsing of ISO 8601 can produce unexpected results, it should not be relied upon (try `new Date("2016-05-16").getDate()` in a time zone west of Greenwich). Also, *match* returns an array.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in comments, you can get the date by parsing the JSON (trimmed in the following for convenience):

```js
var s = '{"Date":"2016-05-16","Package Name":"com.myapp.mobile"}';

var dateString = JSON.parse(s).Date;

document.write(dateString);
```

If you want a Date object, you can then parse the string. Note that using either the *Date* constructor or *Date.parse* for parsing strings is not recommended due to browser inconsistencies. Manually parsing an ISO date is fairly simple, you just need to decide whether to parse it as local or UTC.

Since ECMA-262 requires the date–only ISO format to be parsed as UTC, the following function will do that reliably (and return an invalid date for out of range values):

```js
/* Parse an ISO 8601 format date string YYYY-MM-DD as UTC
** Note that where the host system has a negative time zone
** offset the local date will be one day earlier.
**
** @param {String} s - string to parse
** @returs {Date} date for parsed string. Returns an invalid
**                Date if any value is out of range
*/
function parseISODate(s) {
  var b = s.split(/\D/);
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(b[0], b[1]-1, b[2]));
  return d && d.getMonth() == b[1]-1? d : new Date(NaN);
}

var d = parseISODate('2016-05-16');
document.write('UTC date: ' + d.toISOString() + '<br>' +
               'Local date: ' + d.toString());
```